# How to handle UTF-8 charset with Oracle using FlywayDB

Tags: java, oracle, maven, plsql, flyway

Here is flyway maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <sqlMigrationSuffix>.oracle.sql</sqlMigrationSuffix>
            <placeholderReplacement>true</placeholderReplacement>
            <placeholderPrefix>#[</placeholderPrefix>
            <placeholderSuffix>]</placeholderSuffix>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <table>T00M001</table>
            <locations>
                <location>classpath:/META-INF/flyway/oracle</location>
                <location>classpath:/com/chorke/dbms/jdbcmi/oracle</location>
            </locations>
            <resolvers>
                <resolver>com.chorke.dbms.flyway.resolvers.FlywayResolverImpl</resolver>
            </resolvers>
            <callbacks>
                <callback>com.chorke.dbms.flyway.callbacks.AfterEachMigrate</callback>
                <callback>com.chorke.dbms.flyway.callbacks.BeforeEachMigrate</callback>
            </callbacks>
             <serverId>chorke.flyway.oracle</serverId>
             <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe</url>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.chorke.dbms</groupId>
                <artifactId>chorke-dbms-flyway</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.chorke.dbms</groupId>
                <artifactId>chorke-dbms-oracle</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.chorke.dbms</groupId>
                <artifactId>chorke-dbms-jdbcmi</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Here is *flyway.properties*

```
flyway.encoding: UTF-8
flyway.placeholders.key: value
flyway.placeholders.name: nome
flyway.placeholders.prop: value
```

Here is the snippet of migration script:

```
-- DDL OF T01I001
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE t01i001
(
  t_msg_code VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, t_lang1_msg VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) 
, t_lang2_msg VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) 
, t_entry_user VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) 
, t_entry_date DATE 
, t_upd_user VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) 
, t_upd_date DATE 
);

--  DML OF T01I001
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO t01i001 (t_msg_code,t_lang1_msg,t_lang2_msg,t_entry_user
,t_entry_date,t_upd_user,t_upd_date) VALUES ('00','يوجد سجل أخر لليوم والوقت المحدد'
,'Record already exists for the specified Date and Time.','2'
,to_date('13-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY'),'C',to_date('27-11-2005','DD-MM-YYYY'));

INSERT INTO t01i001 (t_msg_code,t_lang1_msg,t_lang2_msg,t_entry_user
,t_entry_date,t_upd_user,t_upd_date) VALUES ('01'
,'البيانات قد أدخلت من قبل  لرقم الزيارة هذا'
,'Data has already been entered for this Visit Number.','2'
,to_date('13-10-2005','DD-MM-YYYY'),'C',to_date('27-11-2005','DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

Here is the registry for charset of oracle 11g XE R2:

```
NLS_LANG =AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
```

Here is the maven goals:

```
mvn clean install flyway:migrate flyway:info
```

There is two type of problem occurred:

1. **t_lang1_msg** size exceed
2. imported character changed

While we increased **t_lang1_msg** size than migration work fine. but it is automatically converted **يوجد سجل أخر لليوم والوقت المحدد** to **ÙŠÙˆØ¬Ø¯ Ø³Ø¬Ù„ Ø£Ø®Ø± Ù„Ù„ÙŠÙˆÙ… ÙˆØ§Ù„ÙˆÙ‚Øª Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø­Ø¯Ø¯**. Which one unreadable to us.

Any solution regarding to the issue? We appreciate your answer to resolving this issue.

Comment: i have tried your migration script. i couldn't reproduce this issue. does your DB support the Arabic language?. have you tried to insert some data manually? what is the "NLS_CHARACTERSET"?

Comment: It seems the migration script (in UTF-8) is not read as UTF-8. Besides NLS_LANG there is the NLS_CHARACTERSET. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355538/utf-8-from-oracle-tables

Comment: Speical thanks to [Hisham kh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6230174/hisham-kh) to trying this issue. Also thanks to [Joop Eggen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen). Every things was fine but there was bug on ant script. that's `<concat destfile="${file.flyway.sql.concat}" outputencoding="UTF-8" append="true">` instead of  `<concat destfile="${file.flyway.sql.concat}" outputencoding="UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8" append="true">`. For this reason character set converted to unreadable format. Thanks all for your co-operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was no doubt about the configuration of **flyway-maven-plugin**, **flyway.properties** as well as sql script and it's encoding. But there was an problem inside ant script target. Where there was an task to `concat` sql files in specific order for per sprint basis. that's as following:

```
<concat destfile="${file.flyway.sql.concat}" outputencoding="UTF-8"append="true">
    <sort xmlns:rcmp="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.comparators">
        <fileset refid="dir.set.flyway.db.version.build"/>
        <rcmp:name />
    </sort>
</concat>
```

After adding `encoding="UTF-8"` attribute to concat task it is working fine.

```
<concat destfile="${file.flyway.sql.concat}" 
    outputencoding="UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8" append="true">
    <sort xmlns:rcmp="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.comparators">
        <fileset refid="dir.set.flyway.db.version.build"/>
        <rcmp:name />
    </sort>
</concat>
```

That's resolve this issue.